# How to build NDK toolchain in Win 10

Tags: android, android-ndk

I dowloaded `NDK` through Android studio, added `ANDROID_HOME` and `NDK_HOME` variables, and run the below command, but nothing happened:

```sh
${NDK_HOME}/make_standalone_toolchain.py --api 28 --arch x86_64 --install-dir NDK/x86_64
```

Comment: I run this script with python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that in NDK19+ the linker are coming prebuilt, and can be accessed as:

```
[target.x86_64-linux-android]
ar = "C:\Users\${user}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\${NKD_version}\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\x86_64-linux-android-ar"
linker = "C:\Users\${user}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\${NKD_version}\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\x86_64-linux-android23-clang"
```

where the linker should include the `minSdkVersion` for example `x86_64-linux-android23-clang` means `minSdkVersion` is `API 23`

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've set up a .py association to run with Python, Windows won't do that automatically. On Window you should explicitly use `python make_standalone_toolchain.py`.

Note that if you're using NDK r19 or newer you don't need to run that script at all. Follow https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/other_build_systems for the modern advice for this workflow.